# Android application which can parse json recieved from server into meaningful datasets

Tags: android, json

I want to develop an android application which parses json data into some meaningful data sets and accordingly display them into the UI .
I need suggestions on how to go about it.

PS : i have 0 idea of the available options to chose , so different ways to do the same would help me a lot , since i am new to it

Thanks in advance

Comment: first of all start with json parsing in android. it will help you in understanding web service call and get data and parse json data. then decide how to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gson for parsing the data together with some network library like volley or can use retrofit which provide direct parsing with the help of gson and other lib.
To accomplish this you first need to create some relevant Java pojo 
For corresponding json dataset , so that you can use it .
You can generate pojo from this website very easily for any json data

[http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://json%20schema%20to%20pojo)/